# Using data with python nodes

Tags: python, node-editor, pynodes

I have created a number of python nodes inside my own tree. I have one node that takes one input and has a button called "Simulate". This is an operator that is held in another file. Currently all it does is print some text.

The code for my output node is:

```
class SimulateNode(Node, CrowdMasterTreeNode):
'''The simulate node'''
bl_idname = 'SimulateNode'
bl_label = 'Simulate'
bl_icon = 'SOUND'

def init(self, context):
    self.inputs.new('CrowdSocketType', "Crowd")

def copy(self, node):
    print("Copying from node ", node)

def free(self):
    print("Removing node ", self, ", Goodbye!")

def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
    if self.inputs['Crowd'].is_linked == False:
        layout.enabled = False
    layout.scale_y = 1.5
    layout.operator("scene.cm_run_simulation", icon_value=cicon('run_sim'))

def draw_buttons_ext(self, context, layout):
    layout.operator("scene.cm_run_simulation", icon_value=cicon('run_sim'))

def draw_label(self):
    return "Simulate"
```

I have an input node that supplies an integer:

```
class IntegerNode(Node, CrowdMasterTreeNode):
'''The integer node'''
bl_idname = 'IntegerNode'
bl_label = 'Integer'
bl_icon = 'SOUND'

Integer = bpy.props.IntProperty(default=3)

def init(self, context):
    self.outputs.new('NodeSocketInt', "Integer")

def copy(self, node):
    print("Copying from node ", node)

def free(self):
    print("Removing node ", self, ", Goodbye!")

def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
    layout.prop(self, "Integer")

def draw_buttons_ext(self, context, layout):
    layout.prop(self, "Integer")

def draw_label(self):
    return "Integer"
```

[image: integer input and crowd output nodes]

How can I pass any data from any node connected to that output node to the operator?

Comment: The integer node doesn't send data, your sim node gets the data it needs. [This might be what you are after](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14726/935) and [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57187/935) expands some updating options.

Comment: I need to push the data from each node connected to that operator

Comment: When you run your simulation, it needs to read the data that connected nodes have available. Loop over all input sockets and get the value from the connected node then use it in your calculations. The animation nodes and sverchok are the best examples that you can look at.

Comment: How do I access the input sockets?

Comment: It's in the first link I gave.

Comment: OK, I know how to get those. I just need to send all the variables to my operator. I do not care in what order.