# Using the node editor in a private project

Tags: node-editor, development, source-code

Developer question: Is it possible to grab the Node editor (i.e. the one used for compositing) and define my own elements for a totally different project?
I'm just looking for the nifty graphics and interface, and wish to program the functionality myself.

I tried googling to no avail.

Comment: Blender Stack Exchange is more for questions and answers about using Blender, than developing it. Python scripting is still on topic, however pretty much any programming that requires compiling is considered off topic here. Try developer forums devtalk.blender.org. I think you will have a lot better chance of getting an answer there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender, but about it's code.

Comment: Its not completely off topic (https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2216/30849). @gil There are source code maps of the blender repo onlins.

Comment: Blender's UI is pretty blender specific, so it is unlikely to be easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it isn't documented much, blender does support [custom node trees](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/User:Phonybone/Python_Nodes/). You can start with the [custom nodetree template](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/custom_nodes.py) in blenders text editor. You may also find some help searching here for [pynode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14726/935).

Two example projects using custom node trees are [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) and [sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok).

As you are defining each nodes functionality, you don't have to access or modify blenders data, so you could use blenders node editor while making each node read/write data to files.